# Android - Convert ARGB Color to HEX

Tags: java, android, colors

I have an ARGB Color (looks like `255 200 200 000`). I've tried to convert it into Hex format with this code:

---

```
    String col = "#" + Integer.toString(Color.alpha(img.getPixel(j, i)), 16) + 
        Integer.toString(Color.red(img.getPixel(j, i)), 16) + 
        Integer.toString(Color.green(img.getPixel(j, i)), 16) + 
        Integer.toString(Color.blue(img.getPixel(j, i)), 16);
```

---

But I'm gettng this (`#FFC8C8`) instead of (`#FFC8C800`). So all numbers below 10 are writing without zeros.
How I can fix that code to make it work properly?

P.S. Excuse for my English

Comment: Whats wrong with: "#" + Integer.toString(img.getPixel(j,i)), 16)

Comment: It doesn't returns a 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%08X", img.getPixel(j, i));
```